# 3 Way switch with 4 wires to Dimmer with 3 wires

Tags: dimmer-switch

I am replacing a 3 way switch with 4 wires and a ground to a dimmer with 3 wires plus ground. Not sure which wires are what

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks into the back of the box, for that matter?

Comment: That sure looks like a 4-way switch. Are you sure there isn't another 3-way switch controlling this circuit? When you have more than 2 switches controlling a load, the end two are 3-way and the middle ones are 4-way.

Comment: I added a pic of the other switch.

Comment: AFAIK 3-way switches only have 3 wires (not counting ground, and except for some newer electronic types that can act as either single-pole or 3-way or 4-way).

Comment: @jondska -- we need photos that look into the backs of the boxes -- that's the only way we can see how the various wires going out the dimmer are grouped into cables

Comment: @jondska -- can we have a photo looking into the back of the other box please?

Comment: I took the easy way out and swapped it for the 3 way on the other box. Not quite as convenient but it works.Thanks for the effort tho.